# Remove Class after Animation

Tags: jquery, onclick, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

I have a div which I am attempting to animate. The div has an animation class called peek_up applied and I am using else/if to add an animation that lowers the div if peek_up is applied, and raises it if it is not. My problem is that the class I am using to raise obscures the peek_up class, even though peek_up is applied. How would I go about removing the animation used to raise after it is complete?

```
$('#box').on('click', function() {
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.hasClass('peek_down')) {
$this.toggleClass('peek_down').toggleClass('bob_down');
}
else{ 
$this.toggleClass('close_up');
}
});
```

bob_down lowers the div, close_up raises it (and obscures peek_up in doing so).
This code is the closes I have gotten.

http://jsfiddle.net/6sQU5/

Comment: can you make an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) including your HTML, CSS, and JS please. It's hard to discern what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the animations to run as I intended using the setTimeout function, though for some reason it doesn't seem to translate into the jsFiddle. It works fine in my browser.

```
$('#box').on('click', function (){
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.hasClass('peek_down')){
    $this.removeClass('peek_down')
         .addClass('bob_down');
} else{
    $this.removeClass('bob_down')
         .addClass('close_up')
         .addClass('peek_down')
         setTimeout(function(){
    $this.removeClass('close_up')},600);
}
});
```

Comment: After checking in Firefox and Chrome, it works fine. Safari however is a completely static div. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the animation with jQuery or CSS3? By animate do you mean to simply toggle the class? You will need to post your full animation code for people to be able to understand what you're trying to do here.

The jQuery animate() function has the ability to add a post-animation callback function that you could use to achieve what you require. For example:

```
$("#box").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
        top: "+=100"
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Post-animation callback function, add the required code here
    });
});
```

Comment: The animations are CSS, I just added a JSFiddle. The problem is that the peek_down animation is not visible after clicking.

Comment: It seems to work fine in Firefox. Is this a browser issue? The only thing I can notice is that after clicking twice it stops "bobbing", is this what you mean by "obscures"?

Either way, from your title I would conclude that you're going about it the wrong way as setting a class does not give you full control over the CSS animations, you should use jQuery animate() instead for greater control and browser support.

Comment: This is actually part of a group of animations that I am trying to set up to use across different sites as needed, hence being CSS. It is the "bobbing" that I would like to remain consistent, i.e. -bobbing, drop, raise, bobbing, drop, raise.

Comment: Basically you need a way to reset the animation when the close_up animation finishes. You can't avoid having the close_up class applied to the div on post-animation, the "bobbing" won't continue. Unfortunately with CSS3 animations you have no control and no callback to jQuery so you need to replicate the close_up and bob_down CSS3 animations with jQuery animate() then use the callback function to reset the div.

Comment: Shouldn't there at least be a way to call removeClass? Possibly delaying the removal so that the animation can run, and then is removed. I'm not quite ready to accept defeat in this method.